# How to change a number in a list using System linq in C#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list

```
   List < double > newlist = new List<double>{5.0,1.1,2.1,5.1,0.2,5.2,7.5}
```

using System.Linq how to change all values between 5<i<6 to 5.5?

Comment: Mutating an existing list is not something you'd use Linq for - just use a `for` loop.

Comment: Thanks! @MatthewWatson I see. I was simply looking for one-line version of what I want to do.
As others have pointed out, LINQ is for querying data, it is not for doing updates.

Answer (score 0):

approach with linq - that replaces the existing `List<double>` with a new one

```
//[5.0,1.1,2.1,5.5,0.2,5.5,7.5]
newlist = newlist.Select(x => x > 5 && x < 6 ? 5.5d : x).ToList();
```

---

approach with a for loop - that one only changes the affected values

```
for (int i = 0; i < newlist.Count; i++)
{
    if (newlist[i] > 5 && newlist[i] < 6)
    {
        newlist[i] = 5.5d;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's fine if the OP wants to create a new list, but it's not actually changing the numbers IN a list (the question seems to be asking to mutate an existing list).

Comment: @MatthewWatson good point - I've added a classy for-loop